# Where to find iOS Bundle ID without xcode? (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter

I need to find the Bundle ID of my app to add it to my firebase project.

I use VS Code for flutter development, but all the guides online on where to find the bundle id explain how to find it with xcode, which I cannot have since I have a PC

Comment: did my answer was helpful? Can you mark it as the answer for your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the root folder of your project you probably have a file called **Info.plist** if you open this file in any text/code editor you can search by **CFBundleIdentifier**. The next line will show your Bundle ID.

Comment: That's great! But mine says ``$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`` as the value

Can I change it? I want to use the value that I have put in my Firebase...

Is putting the name from my firebase is enough or should I leave like that because it's a variable of some sort and it gets my flutter app name on its own?

Comment: @HusseinAl-Mosawi yes that is a variable to another property, instead of changing the CFBundleIdentifier you should change the PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER here is the documentation that shows how to change the PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/managing_your_app_s_information_property_list

Comment: Must be mentioned that as you said this is a variable. In order to get the FINAL bundle identifier you must go to ios\Runner\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj and there look for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER

Answer (score 10):

1. Inside Runner.xcodeproj folder, open project.pbxproj
2. Then to search, press **CTRL+F**
3. Search for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
4. You will get your ios bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

It's the value inside the `String` tag in file `Info.plist` located in the folder `ios/Runner` .

[image]

**Bundle ID** will be  here : `<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>`

[image]